# Docker: Connection from debian to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, debian

I'm trying to run a E-learning community server (ECS)
https://www.freeit.de/en/campusconnect_ecs/index.html
on a docker-compose system. This ECS needs a postgres-DB to be installed. So this is my first try

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  debian:
    container_name: debian_test
    build: './stuff'
    restart: on-failure
    command: ["sleep","infinity"]
    links:
       - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

and                                                                                    stuff/Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
mysql-common libpq5 libsqlite3-0 openssl libxml2 libxslt1.1 libssl1.0.2 libmariadbclient18 libevent-2.0-5 libevent-core-2.0-5 libevent-extra-2.0-5 libreadline7 apt-transport-https
```

So I have debian in the first container and postgres in the other container. Now I enter the debian container, where I have installed ECS...

```
docker exec -it debian_test bash
```

...run the ECS. But here I receive the error:

```
Called from /opt/ecs4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How is it possible to connect these two containers?

Best,
Alex

Comment: You should be able to set an environment variable `PGHOST=db` in the `docker-compose.yml` file, or otherwise configure your application to connect to that host name.  See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for additional details.  You should not need the obsolete `links:` option and I'd recommend deleting it.

Comment: I don't see anything programming related in your question, so youmight be better off asking on [sf] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

First: Where is the database-connection defined? Only in the compose file? Normaly you should set at least the database-server-name somewhere.

Second: Check if the containers are running in the same network?

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_ID OR NAME
```

The section is "NetworkSettings" -> "Networks"